# Is it necessary to incorporate testing into my rails app BEFORE upgrading versions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, integration-testing

1. I am upgrading rails 3.0.20 to rails 4.0 (current ruby version 1.8.7), how important is it for me to build unit testing into my application before starting the update? Integration testing? Acceptance testing? End to end testing?
2. Are ALL of these ABSOLUTELY crucial to incorporate before starting my updates?
3. How about if I focus on upgrading rails from 3.0 to 3.2 first (as per my employer's request)? Would any of these tests become less "necessary" and could be temporarily put aside? (given that the difference between rails 3.0 to 3.2 is not as large and significant as the difference to rails 4.0)

Note that my company's app has been working smoothly for a couple of years (without any testing mechanisms whatsoever), and updating to rails 3.2/4.0 is of HIGHER priority than incorporating testing into the app at this point in time, thus proceeding with the rails upgrade without creating any tests would currently be preferred.

Any insights, advice, warnings, would be greatly greatly appreciated. I am a novel programmer and was asked to take on this upgrading rails project on my own.

Comment: Haha. How "necessary" is it to ever test? Anyway, I suspect your question is more along the lines of "What [breaking] changes are there when migrating from RoR 3 -> 3.2 -> 4?" Because, srsly .. otherwise what *is* the point of testing?

Comment: What's a `novel programmer`?  Testing is always important... it's ingrained in the entire Rails community.  Frankly I would get tests in there as soon as you possibly can. But if your employer wants it to be upgraded to Rails 4 ASAP - maybe do that first?  The upgrade isn't *awful*, just a lot of deprecations.  Of course, you're at 3.0 so you have to go through all the asset pipeline changes and such too... so it might be more involved.

Comment: I just started working a month and a half ago, and finished reading all the introduction to rails guides notes (Models, Views, Controllers). My real question is: "OK, I get that testing is important, what tests should I implement before starting the upgrade? should I focus on unit testing first? The code is working fine, and has been for two years, so maybe I could push that off for now? How about integration testing? I just want to know what type of tests is it most worth while to spend time reading up on and implement because they will make the upgrading process that much easier for me.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comment that testing is always important.  There should be tests in any case, never mind about when upgrading rails.

I would recommend having tests in place before doing anything else.  It could save you a lot of hassle later.  Quoted from the rails 4 release notes:

"If you're upgrading an existing application, it's a great idea to have good test coverage before going in."

In the end, I suppose it's up to your employer as they're paying you, but if they want to make you upgrade rails without an automated test suite you need to make it clear to them that they will likely be opening themselves up to various problems/bugs.  Do they have any thorough manual quality control (human testers)? (I don't know if you were just referring to automated tests when you said they have no testing mechanisms.)

In any case, how painful the upgrade is depends on the app.  Things like its size and the rails features it uses would be a factor.  If you don't have extensive knowledge of the app's code base, it's going to be more difficult to know the implications of the differences in the rails versions and writing tests would be a good way to get to know the codebase!

You mentioned that the current version of ruby being used is 1.8.7.  This means you'll need to upgrade ruby too, because rails 4 requires at least ruby 1.9.3.

Have you looked at the release notes for the versions of rails you'll be upgrading through/to?  They contain information about changes that have been made and pointers on the upgrade process.  They recommend the upgrade path 3.0 -> 3.1.x -> 3.2.x -> 4.0.x

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/3_1_release_notes.html

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/3_2_release_notes.html

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html

This seems to be where the upgrade guide for 3.2 -> 4.0 actually is (linked to from the 4.0 release notes), and it also contains the upgrade guides from the 3.1 and 3.2 release notes:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#upgrading-from-rails-3-2-to-rails-4-0

Comment: Basically there are no type of tests of any kind whatsoever in their rails application, nor do they have a manual quality control. However the size of the application is not that big, and there aren't that many user interface pages. The employees should be able to tests out the full scope of the site rather quickly (this isn't an IT company). I posted this question exactly because the rails guides warn against upgrading version without having solid testing. Maybe you could be more specific about what tests you think are THE MOST important for me to implement before upgrading ruby and rails?

Answer (score 0):

Basically I went through the upgrade without any integrated testing.
I had to manually check the functionality of the site is working, about 90% was working fine and the rest I had to catch.
Most issues involved gem compatibility, some had to do with JS libraries that I choose to include in the application.js file in my assets folder.
If your app is of moderate size and you can spend a week or so testing it yourself manually, I wouldn't worry about having any integrated testing, as important as it is to have.